# How to Manage items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, styles, font-size

I have `recyclerView` with two texts, first is Title (Parent) and second is text list (Child), and in Settings Activity I saved font size in SaveData Class.

1- How to change Parent and Child font size from SaveData Class?

2- How to change all numbers style in Child list?

3- How to remove or replace some sign (ex: , ; ') from Child list?

1. In Parent Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.section.text = list[position].section
        holder.viewDataBinding.childRv.apply {
            adapter = ChildAdapter(list[position].list)
        }
}
```

2. In Child Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.childText.text = list[position]
}
```

3. In Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val mainBinding = binding.mainRecycler
        mainBinding.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Activity)
            adapter = ParentAdapter(list)
        }
}
```

4. in SaveData Class:

```
class SaveData(context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun setFontSize(size: Float?) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("FontSize", size!!)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun loadFontSize(): Float {
        val size = sharedPreferences.getFloat("FontSize", 0f)
        return size
    }
}
```

for digits style I tried this:

```
private fun digitsStyle() {
        var txt = getString(R.string.text)
        "\\d+".toRegex().findAll(txt)
            .flatMap { it.groupValues }
            .forEach {
                txt = txt.replace(it, "<sup><font color=red>$it</font></sup>")
            }
        text.text = Html.fromHtml(txt)
    }
```

for replace sign I tried this:

```
fun replaceSign(tv: TextView) {
        var string = getString(R.string.text).replace(",", "")
            .replace(";", "").replace("'", "")
        tv.text = string
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I only understand your first question, the other questions are completely unclear for me, please explain more.

Comment: Thank you, but by your answer I think you need to read my question again. the items are in List not just String text. how to change numbers style and replace signs in this List?? and where put your methods in Adapter??

Comment: Your questions are hard to understand, edit your post, and I will help you, because I think it's easy to achieve your needs, you just need to make your question clear

Comment: I edited it. read it now..